# Possible Bug With positive_rep Field?

Tags: bug

I'm looking through my /users/{id}/reputation and I think I see a possible bug regarding how positive_rep is calculated when someone upvotes your question.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/40906/reputation

I have 10 positive rep for my C# question (on_date=1273991678). Looking through my reputation history on the SO site, I see that I only had 1 upvote for that question in the last month.

That leads me to believe that the positive_rep should be 5, and not 10, since I only actually received 5 rep.

Comment: i am seeing what appears to be odd data being returned by /reputation as well.

Answer (score 1):

I see two upvotes on May 17 in that question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/632571/timeline).

I also only see +5 rep in your [rep graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632571/c-book-for-the-casual-beginner-c-programmer).  Even though that  doesn't show votes, it doesn't match the API results.

There must be a bug somewhere, but it isn't confined to the API: I can only account for the timeline/rep-graph difference through possible caching for the rep graph, and that seems unlikely.  (The graph does show this isn't related to the rep cap as you didn't even get close that day.)

Comment: When I look at my recent rep in the last couple months, I only see 1 upvote (5 rep) for that question. Something seems off.